# Dual Boot Configuration with SSD and HDD

Tags: centos, windows, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I'm very new to Linux. I have been using Windows/Mac during my whole life, but now I have decided to use Linux.
So I'm trying to configure a dual boot system with Windows 10 and CentOS 7. I already have installed both of these OSs:  CentOS 7 on one partition of the HDD and Windows 10 on the SSD (which is not partitioned).  I found a great [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-u_va6ZxOk) on how to edit `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. The author edits the `grub.cfg` file, adding these lines:

```
menuentry "Windows #" {
  set root='(hd0, 0)'
  chainloader + 1
}
```

`hd0,0` does not work for booting Windows (which I have installed on my SSD). At boot I have "Windows 10" in the menu, but it isn't working.

Edit:
I have already reinstalled both OS in UEFI and now it works.

Comment: what do you mean with Windows 10 on SSD (no partition)? and are you using EFI?

Comment: I mean there are 2 physical disks. SSD and HDD. HDD I have partitioned and SSD not. I don't know what EFI does mean. I have used lsblk command and HDD have sda1 and sda2 and SSD  have only sdb1.

Comment: ok then Windows automatically partitioned your ssd (sdb1 is this automatically created partition). EFI is the successor of BIOS, if your mainboard is not older than 2 years, you can be quite sure that you have such a mainboard.

Comment: I think this it is BIOS. I run [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS and the echo is BIOS. However when appears my mother boards splash-screen it says press DEL or F2 to access UEFI BIOS setup. Also now I can't boot Windows, even if I choose my SSD from boot menu.

Comment: If your windows disk is sdb1 then I think the root line for the Windows menuentry in grub.cfg should be: `set root='(hd1, 0)'` i.e. sda=hd0,sdb=hd1 (and ',0' indicates partition 1). It's worth a try anyway.

Comment: Also consider virtual-box: you can run MS-Windows in a virtual machine. This way you can run both at the same time, and no duel boot problems. (it won't work well for gaming, and 3D CAD, but for other situations, on a modern device, it is plenty fast enough, there are even some situation where MS-Windows runs faster in Virtual-box, than on the raw hardware.)

Comment: So is it now working for you?